# While connecting to Rinkby test network its giving me error genesis mismatch

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, genesis, erc20

I tried to connect to the Rinkby test network on Ethereum by using the command:

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath "C:\Program Files\Geth"
```

but it's giving me this error message:

> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: genesis mismatch:
> 00x6341fd3daf94b748c72ced5a5b26028f24

I don't know what's happening - can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

The Genesis block is not syncing so I deleted Ethereum file on my computer under users/program files then I reinstalled Geth latest version and the genesis block started syncing and was able to connect to Rinkby test network to test my application